# What does StringInterpolationSegment do? (swift)

Tags: swift, variables

I continued on my math question project, and it could now generate questions, so I need to try to use a global variable to use my answer's in generating the answer itself and putting the answer randomly into one of 4 choices. I decided to put a secret label outside of my view that shows the answer. Here's my code:

```
    //important stuff
@IBOutlet var secretAnsarrrrr: UILabel!
//useless code
        //declare the value of secretAnsarrrr
        secretAnsarrrrr.text = String(answer)
        numA.text = String(Int(randomNumber))
        numB.text = String(Int(randomNumber2))
    }
    generateQuestion()
}
var optionAnswer:UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(4)
@IBAction func answerA(sender: UIButton) {
    var otherAns:String = String(secretAnsarrrrr) //error
    if optionAnswer == 0 {
        optionA.text = secretAnsarrrrr.text
    }
```

Doing so gives me the error of 'Missing argument label: StringInterpolationSegment in call'. It tells me to place it behind 'secretAnsarrrrr' in the parentheses. What does stringInterpolationSegment do and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`secretAnsarrrrr` is not a string itself - it is a `UILabel` which also contains information like color and font. You need to tell Swift to use its `text` property:

```
 var otherAns:String = String(secretAnsarrrrr.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this error, and after some head scratching, I realised that I needed to unwrap an optional integer which I was trying to parse with String(...). As soon as I added the exclamation mark, the problem was solved:

```
var num: Int? = 1
var str = String(num!)
```

Answer (score 0):

it is Better to write:

```
var num: Int? = 1
var str = num.map { String($0) } // if num == nil then str = nil else str = string representation
```